# Syntax Error в лямбда функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача программы: возвратить сумму всех чисел до 1000, кратных 5 или 3.

```
def multi(max_num = 1000):
    for n in range(max_num): lambda n: k_num.append(n) if n % 5 == 0 or n % 3 == 0
    return sum(k_num)
```

Происходит ошибка:

```
    for n in range(max_num): lambda n: k_num.append(n) if n % 5 == 0 or n % 3 == 0
                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Почему? Прошу вашей помощи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Где у вас определена переменная `k_num`?
Зачем в решении `lambda`?

Решайте с помощью list comprehension или определяйте список `k_num` до цикла for, в цикле проверяйте на кратность и если True, то добавляйте к списку `n`.

P.S.: Не пытайтесь все на одну строку запихнуть, вы себе только понимание программы усложняете.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, почему < SyntaxError > ? Ведь интерпретатор *допускает* в отдельных случаях написание составных инструкций в одной *физической* строке. Конечно, код не рабочий, но интерпретатору это и не важно - он обнаружил формальное нарушение: не закончена конструкция выражения < *(...) if (...) **else (...)*** >.

Во-вторых, сама задача скорее "на формулу", а не на полный перебор - представим, что max_num будет 10^18, и сколько лет придётся ожидать ответа?
Между тем, применяя принцип "включения-исключения", получим быстрый ответ - надо к сумме чисел, кратных 3, прибавить сумму чисел, кратных 5, и затем вычесть сумму чисел, кратных 15 (так как они посчитаются дважды).
Вот примерный код:

```
def multi(max_num):
    max_num -= 1   ## само число max_num не считаем - так ведь?
    n3 = max_num // 3
    n5 = max_num // 5
    n15 = max_num // 15
    return 3*(n3*(n3+1)//2) + 5*(n5*(n5+1)//2) - 15*(n15*(n15+1)//2)
```